# how to generate a new component using viewcontainerref?

Tags: angular

My ng template in master.html is as follows:

```
<div class="tab-content" >
            <div class="tab-pane fade show" role="tabpanel" *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [id]="tab.itemName" [ngClass]="{ 'active': activeItem == tab.itemName}">
                <ng-template #appComponentLoader>
                </ng-template>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and in  my master.ts i am generating a new component as follows:

```
import { SecondComponentComponent } from './../second-component/second-component.component';
import { FirstComponentComponent } from './../first-component/first-component.component';
import { ComponentLoaderDirective } from './../../component-loader.directive';
import { Component, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild, QueryList, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-masters',
  templateUrl: './masters.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./masters.component.css']
})
export class MastersComponent implements OnInit {
  masterMenuItems = [
    { itemName: "Countries", displayName: "First Component",Component:FirstComponentComponent },
    { itemName: "ClientLocations", displayName: "Second Component",Component:SecondComponentComponent},
     ];

  @ViewChild('appComponentLoader', {read: ViewContainerRef}) componentLoader;
  activeItem: string;
  tabs=[];


  constructor(public componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  menuItemClick(clickMasterMenu:any){
    //console.log(clickMasterMenu)

    this.activeItem=clickMasterMenu.itemName;
    let matchingTabs=this.tabs.filter((tab)=>{
      return tab.itemName == clickMasterMenu.itemName;

    }

    )


    if (matchingTabs.length == 0)
    {
      this.tabs.push({
        tabIndex:this.tabs.length,
        itemName:clickMasterMenu.itemName,
        displayName:clickMasterMenu.displayName

      });

    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   console.log(this.componentLoader)
    //   var componentLoadersArray = this.componentLoader.toArray();
    //   var componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(clickMasterMenu.Component);
    //   var viewContainterRef = componentLoadersArray[this.tabs.length - 1].viewContainerRef;
    //   viewContainterRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    // }, 100);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(this.componentLoader);
      //var componentLoaderArray=this.componentLoader.toArray();

      var componentFactory=this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(clickMasterMenu.Component);
      var ref=this.componentLoader.createComponent(componentFactory);

      // var viewcontainerref=this.componentLoader.viewContainerRef
      // viewcontainerref.createComponent(componentFactory);
    },100);


  }

  }
}
```

My issue is when i am clicking on the second component,it is getting created and it is being rendered.but just below the first component.My requirement is that the second component should be created in a new way ie irrespective of the position of the first components and vice versa.
Any help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to understand your problem.

1. You want to clean all the components present in your ViewContainerRef before adding others. You will need to clean the container:

```
this.componentLoader.clear();
```

2. You want to keep all of your components in the container. You will have to manage this with CSS, nothing more.

Hope to have helped you a little, see you soon!